# Running Powershell Start-Process With -Credential makes script hang (Windows Server 2012)

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, powershell-4.0

I have come across a rare occurrence as this cannot be replicated on my own machine however on one of our Windows Server 2012 instances it occurs.

The script I invoke looks like this

```
$arg="D:\Scripts\test.ps1"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword

Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList $arg
```

This piece of code just **hangs** on the server while this

```
$arg="D:\Scripts\test.ps1"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword

Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList $arg
```

runs just fine, the test.ps1 script only contains the following so it should not be breaking since it works normally but just with the seperate user credential it does not work.

```
write-host "Output:"
write-host ""
Write-Host ("----------------------------------------------------------------")
```

Also I have tested using my user credentials even instead of our service user and i get the same issue so it seems to be an issue with Start-Process itself when ran with the -Credential verb.

If anyone has dealt with this before any help would be greatly appreciated. I have also tried changing the execution policy on the server to remote signed but also to no avail.

Comment: use Exit at the end of the script. PS is holding the session I believe

Comment: Even if i only run Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Credential $Credential the same happens, the process is not even starting off. Even with Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -Credential $Credential it does not work

Comment: why dont you use a job in that case. `Start-Job ` will be much easier

Comment: here is a link for that. [Start-Job Use](https://onejourneymultipletechnologies.blogspot.in/2016/10/blog-post_23.html)

Comment: OK thanks will give that a try quick

Comment: If you are getting any issue. do let us know

Comment: Ok i will cause the main reason why i am struggeling with this is that the job which run as a side process is a program called Control M, and it cannot run a process as a seperate user, so we've had to adjust our powershell to try end execute the script with the elevated user credentials supplied and now start process is giving this issue.

Comment: Ok so Start-Job does the exact same thing so i think this has to be something with the server blocking scripts run as seperate users somehow since this time i only ran this

Start-Job -credential $credential -scriptblock {write-host "something to do"}

And all it does is hang

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134377/discussion-between-ranadip-dutta-and-hano-johannes-rossouw).

Comment: So just to let you know, It seems the security and group policy settings on the machine are very strict and is blocking the script running as a different user. We have decided to rather just let the running service Control M run as a domain account with access to SSAS then the elevated permission part is no longer required

Comment: great. :) Atleast that narrowed down the issue