# Start-Process hangs when used with -Credential

Tags: powershell, start-process

During my continuous delivery pipeline I would like to run Powershell script which starts my .NET Core application used to update database. Problem is user used TFS agent has no permissions to connect to MSSQL server. That's why I would like to run this process as different user. What I'm doing right now is

```
$username = 'DOMAIN\username'
$password = 'password'

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $securePassword

Start-Process -FilePath 'dotnet' -ArgumentList 'MyApp.dll' -NoNewWindow -Wait -Credential $credential
```

Running this script causes Powershell window to freeze. I can't do `Ctrl+C` nor `Ctrl+Z`. The same command, but without `-Credential` part works fine. On my local machine everything works fine even with `-Credential` so this has to be some kind of configuration issue.

I was looking for an answer and stumbled upon [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934674/running-powershell-start-process-with-credential-makes-script-hang-windows-ser), but [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934674/running-powershell-start-process-with-credential-makes-script-hang-windows-ser#comment71055191_41934674) doesn't help me much.

I tried to set up execution policy to `Bypass` and `Unrestricted`. I also tried to configure `Turn on Script Execution` in Local Group Policy Editor > Computer Configuration > Windows Components > Windows PowerShell to 
Allow all scripts, but also without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'dotnet' -ArgumentList 'MyApp.dll' -NoNewWindow -Credential $credential -PassThru| Wait-Process -Timeout 5 -ErrorAction Stop
```

Instead of directly giving `-Wait`.

PS: You can put some try catch also which will help you out.